# ObjectQuery not attaching entities instantiated using Named Type Constructor to the context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have an entity SQL query that creates an entity based on resulting values.

**The problem is the entities are not attached to the context. The web control using the ObjetQuery requires the entities be attached to the context to retrieve supporting data through navigation controls.**

Manually adding the results will attach the entity to the context but the ObjectQuery is being used as a datasource. Unfortunately attaching the entities to the context manually is not an option as a Telerik control (RadGrid) requires the object query for additional functionality (Sorting, Filtering, etc).

Here is the code generating the object query (the function is a method of the generated ObjectContext):

```
    public ObjectQuery<Invoice_Payment> getInvoicePaymentList(int PaymentID)
    {
        ObjectQuery<Invoice_Payment> oq = this.CreateQuery<Invoice_Payment>(@"SELECT VALUE DotNetNuke.Modules.Collections.Model.Invoice_Payment(Inv.ID, @PaymentID, IP.Amount, IP.TimeStamp, IP.LastModifiedBy, Inv.Company) 
                        FROM Collections.Invoices As Inv Left Outer Join 
                        Collections.Invoice_Payments As IP On IP.Invoice = Inv.ID && IP.Payment = @PaymentID Left Outer Join
                        Collections.Payments As P On P.ID = @PaymentID
                        WHERE (Inv.Invoice_Outstanding_Balance.ID is not null && Inv.Customer = P.Customer) || IP.Payment is not null
                        ORDER BY Inv.Document_Date
                    ", new ObjectParameter("PaymentID", PaymentID));
        oq = oq.Include("InvoiceDetails").Include("PaymentDetails");
        oq.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;

        return oq;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong or what could I have misconfigured for the resulting entities to not attach to the calling context?

---

**Edit:**

After a little more investigation I have found that my problem is not isolated to this one entity type but all entity types that are instantiated using ***Named Type Constructor***. My problem is better defined as:

How can entities instantiated using the Named Type Constructor in entity SQL be attached to the context when the query is executed?